# In Unity, how can I remove multiple components when removing one in editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a component called ContainerDescriptor. When I remove it by right click and then left click remove component, I'd like that it removes other components as well, referenced in the script.

[image: remove component]

I'm currently using OnDestroy() in ContainerDescriptor.cs.
I'm also using the [ExecuteAlways] attribute so OnDestroy() is called in editor mode as well.

Say I have a reference towards another component called attachedContainer and I want to remove it when destroying containerDescriptor. Currently I'm doing the following.

in ContainerDescriptor.cs :

```
[ExecuteAlways]
public class ContainerDescriptor : MonoBehaviour
{

    // ... some code

    public AttachedContainer attachedContainer;
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
            if (Application.isPlaying)
            {
                Destroy(attachedContainer);
            }
            else
            {
                DestroyImmediate(attachedContainer, true);
            }
    }

    // ... some more code
}
```

It works well in Editor mode but when I press play I get the following error every time :

> Destroying object multiple times. Don't use DestroyImmediate on the
> same object in OnDisable or OnDestroy.

But Destroy() only works in play mode ! So I don't see which options are left for me.

Ideally, I could remove those components by calling DestroyImmediate() somewhere else, in some method OnRemoveComponent called when selecting remove Component in Editor, but I can't find anything like that in documentation.

If it's relevant, I'm using Unity 2019.3.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to check if the object you're going to destroy is not destroyed already?

```
        else
        {
           if(attachedContainer!=null) 
           {
               DestroyImmediate(attachedContainer, true);
           }
        }
```

Please note that I haven't tested the code above. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it doesn't change the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom editor does the trick. I declare as references every component I want to delete in the custom editor script. I assign the references in containerDescriptor to the references in containerDescriptorEditor. I then use the onDestroy of the custom editor :

In containerDescriptorEditor.cs :

```
public class ContainerDescriptorEditor : Editor
{
    private ContainerDescriptor containerDescriptor;
    private AttachedContainer attachedContainer;
    private AttachedContainerGenerator attachedContainerGenerator;  
    private ContainerInteractive containerInteractive;
    private VisibleContainer visibleContainer;

    // ... some code

    public void OnEnable()
    { 
        containerDescriptor = (ContainerDescriptor)target;
        attachedContainer = containerDescriptor.attachedContainer;  
        containerInteractive = containerDescriptor.containerInteractive;
        visibleContainer = containerDescriptor.visibleContainer;     
    } 

    // ... some more code

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if(containerDescriptor == null)
        {
            RemoveContainer();
        }
    }

    private void RemoveContainer()
    {
        DestroyImmediate(attachedContainer, true);
        DestroyImmediate(attachedContainerGenerator, true);
        DestroyImmediate(containerInteractive, true);
        DestroyImmediate(visibleContainer, true);
    }

// ...
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script I wrote to resolve the issue.

https://github.com/saadasghar96/Unity/blob/master/Utility/MultiComponentCopierCleaner.cs

Go under Earth People Studio > Multi-Component Cleaner

If you leave the 'component' field empty in the Multi-Component Cleaner, it will remove every type of component. Type in "rigidbody" (casings don't matter as long as the component is partially named correctly) and the script will do the rest.

Be sure to back up the object you're cleaning in case things go wrong.